# Doctrine 1.2 Column Naming Conventions for Many To Many Relationships

Tags: php, mysql, orm, doctrine

I'm working with an existing database schema, and trying to setup two Doctrine models with a Many to Many relationship, [as described in this document](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/defining-models/en#relationships:join-table-associations:many-to-many)

When creating tables from scratch, I have no trouble getting this working.  However, the existing join tables use a different naming convention that what's described in the Doctrine document. Specifically

```
Table 1
--------------------------------------------------
table_1_id
....other columns....

Table 2
--------------------------------------------------
table_2_id
....other columns....

Join Table
--------------------------------------------------
fktable1_id
fktable_2_id
```

Basically, the previous developers prefaced all foreign keys with an `fk`.

From the examples I've seen and some brief experimenting with code, it appears that Doctrine 1.2 **requires** that the join table use the same column names as the tables it's joining in

> 1. Is my assumption correct?
> 2. If so, has the situation changed in Doctrine 2?
> 3. If the answers to either of the above are true, how do you configure the models so that all the columns "line up"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look [at the docs](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/defining-models/en#relationships:join-table-associations:many-to-many) regarding N:M relations.

When you look at

```
$this->hasColumn('user_id', 'integer', null, array(
                'primary' => true
            )
        );
```

from the docs, you see that is is up to you how you name the column in your join model.

Since you have an existing database, why not **generate the models via Doctrine**? The [API](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/1.2/doctrine/doctrine_core.html#generateModelsFromDb%28%29) shows you the needed options for this. I used that myself and it works pretty good. Sometimes you may need some cleanups if you have a compliacted structure but the generated files are a very good start.

Comment: I did generate my models from the DB, but it didn't pick up the relationships.  Is there a special option you need to pass into the generateModelsFromDb method to tell doctrine to take its best guess at relationships?

Comment: No, it should be fine when you generate it. Have you tested the generated models in your application?

Comment: Ah, I think I see what you were getting at here.  In case it wasn't clear for others, aliasing the database column names to what doctrine wanted for field names did the trick ($this->hasColumn('fksection_id as section_id')

Answer (score 1):

You just have to set the local and foreign parts to match your column names

```
Table1:
  columns:
    table_1_id: int
    ....
  relations:
    Table2:
      foreignAlias: FromSecond
      local: table_1_id
      foreign: fktable1_id
      refClass: JoinTable
Table2:
  columns:
    table_2_id: int
    ....
  relations:
    Table1:
      foreignAlias: FromFirst
      local: table_2_id
      foreign: fktable2_id
      refClass: JoinTable
JoinTable:
  columns:
    fktable1_id: int
    fktable2_id: int
  relations:
    Table1:
    Table2:
```

Comment: I'm not jumping into YAML immediately to avoid the whole "too many new things at once" mental problem.  What sort of classes/setup methods does the above generate?